# why my Flex Builder wouldn't show errors?

Tags: flexbuilder

i installed flex builder 3,it never shows immediage error,to see errors i need to run appliction..what prob with this builder? need to be installed any extra plugins ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to build a project to see errors in it - click `Build Project` or `Build All (Ctrl-B)` option in the `Project` menu to do this.

Tick the `Build Automatically` option in the `Project` menu to auto-build the project every time you save an associated file in the project.

Comment: @Amar: How can i get user role in flex,i mean when the user enter his credentials am returning true/false.now i want to redirect that user to his panel depending on his role..how can i do that ?

Comment: It takes some time to compile - that is quite normal.

Comment: Something like `if(role == ROLE1) showPanelOne(); else showPanelTwo();` - you might wanna checkout flex states http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/quickstart/creating_states/ - ask it as a new question if you have more doubts.

Comment: yah..some thing like as u said...but i donno satates ion flex....just am entered in to flex field

Comment: @amar:No amar, i want something like viewStacking

Comment: `if(role == ROLE1) viewStack.selectedIndex = 0; else viewStack.selectedIndex = 1;` Start a new thread.